# react componentdidmount firing each time when using router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've got 2 components in my Router each with a ComponentDidMount that contain AXIOS to retrieve json to load a table. The issue is I only want to execute the AXIOS the first time each Component is routed to; not successive times.

I only need the JSON data loaded initially, but not on successive renders. How do I not execute Component Did Render when 'Subprocedures' is clicked successive times?

Menu/NavBar:

Home / Subprocedures / Buttons

Router:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <ul className="header">
      <li><Link to="/">Document WebApps</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/subprocedures">Subprocedures</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/buttons">Buttons</Link></li>
    </ul>

    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/subprocedures" component={Subprocedures} />
    <Route path="/buttons" component={Buttons} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Component:

```
class Subprocedures extends React.Component {
...
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://www.acme.com:4448/api/DOCJSON.pgm?submit=SUBPROC`)
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data.data.children.map(obj => obj.data);
        this.setState({ posts });
      });
  }
```

Comment: not sure but maybe try global state with redux and a key like hasFired to ensure it only fires if hasFired is false and set it to true when you go to that route and in the componentDidMount

Comment: Thanks, I thought there would be a more standardized way to do this since this seems pretty common to me(newbie speaking)- having users switch back and forth between menu options that have **ComponentDidMount**.

Comment: this is not a fairly straightforward problem. People want to refresh the page on every visit because the backend data might have been updated between visits. Caching data or maintaining global variables (to check fetches) could easily turn the application too complex to maintain. Please look into graphQL clients like relay/apollo which solve exactly these kind of problems

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll do that. You're correct- most apps want to  refers the data in case it changed .In my situation I know it won't so I just want to load each table once. I was able to condition the ComponentDidMount but then the tables were empty on successive renders.